# Video don' t start playing but instead throw DOMException

Tags: javascript, html, video, ecmascript-6

I have just created  video object on fly , then add 2 attributes such as  **source** and **muted** before  appending the video object in the document and finally use method **play()** to play the added video as illustrated below.

```
let v = document.createElement("video");
v.setAttribute("src","videoplayback.mp4");
v.setAttribute("muted","muted");

document.body.appendChild(v);
v.play().catch((e)=>{ console.log(e)});  // it returns DomException why?
```

So can someone can tell me What is wrong or solve  this for me .

**NB :one image of the video is displayed but it is not running..**

Comment: `it returns DomException` ... no other details in the error?

Comment: most likely it's because `videoplayback.mp4` doesn't exist ... in firefox, the **FULL ERROR** is `DOMException: "The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission."` - you must be using `chrum` - its console is pathetically useless, isn't it

Comment: @Jaromanda X  If I remove the catch it gives me: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Comment: yes, so you're using Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a new feature that has been added to Google Chrome - media (e.g. videos and sounds) cannot be played before the user interacts actively with the page (click). Just add a `created` variable, put all your code inside a `click` handler, and create the video if `created` is `false`, and set `created` to `true`:

```
let created = false;
$(document).on("click", () => {
    if (!created) {
        created = true;
        let v = document.createElement("video");
        v.setAttribute("src","videoplayback.mp4");
        v.setAttribute("muted","muted");
        document.body.appendChild(v);
        v.play().catch((e)=>{ console.log(e)});
    }
});
```

Comment: that must be a google chrum thing - perhaps it pays to specify which browser this "feature" has been added to rather than thinking everyone uses the browser you use

Comment: Sorry I use chrome

Comment: @JackBashford Bashford It works with your method, But can tell me more why?

Comment: Because with Chrome, you need to interact with the page before a video can play (with some exceptions, like YouTube). This just makes sure you have clicked the page before it creates and plays the video.

Answer (score 2):

by default, not just in Chrome but also in Mozilla Firefox and other browsers the video autoplay command is being denied if the Video contains audio and is not muted.
The only way around it is a javascript forced autoplay with audio.
However if you set the video tag to muted="muted" and autoplay the video will still autoplay even if you have set your browser to not to autoplay videos onload.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This does not answer the question

Comment: Actually it does because it gives devs a hint of what the actual cause of the issue is and what needs to be done to get around this browser default, which is to set the video tag to <video id="myVideo" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted"><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video> and then target the tag ID with a javascript to un-mute / change the audio volume of the video once it has started the autoplay.

Comment: Yeah, it does. Simplified, you either need user interaction (click) or non-audible autoplay (i.e. muted).

Comment: Okay, their answer and your comments gave the solution. For auto-play, the video has to start playing in muted mode.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem obvious, however, make sure you don't have an extension installed that is preventing the video from playing. In my case, a site I recently completed has been working fine. I went back to take a look at the site and got this error message: VM476:96 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play method is not allowed by the user agent.

Within a few minutes, I realized I recently installed AutoplayStopper which of course was preventing the video from running auto play.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your browser default settings. It has set not to play any Audio or video.
Firefox:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay